# Grab specific objects within another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have this js object

```
{
  "2015": {
    "11": {
      "10": {
        "Family & Friends\nGames": {
          "c": 2
        },
        "Collectible\nGames": {
          "c": 1
        },
        "Logic Games\n": {
          "c": 1
        },
        "Kids Games\n": {
          "c": 1
        }
      },      
    },
    "Family & Friends\nGames": {
      "c": 9
    },
    "Collectible\nGames": {
      "c": 2
    },
    "Logic Games\n": {
      "c": 4
    },
    "Kids Games\n": {
      "c": 6
    },
    "Classic Games\n": {
      "c": 3
    },
    "Preschool\nGames": {
      "c": 5
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "id": [
      "[CLY]2",
      "[CLY]7",
      "[CLY]6",
      "[CLY]1",
      "[CLY]4",
      "[CLY]3"
    ],
    "segments": [
      "id",
      "title"
    ],
    "title": [
      "Family & Friends\nGames",
      "Collectible\nGames",
      "Logic Games\n",
      "Kids Games\n",
      "Classic Games\n",
      "Preschool\nGames"
    ]
  }
}
```

Im trying to subtract the same objects right above "meta" that match the keys under "title". I accomplished this using ruby with the following code

```
     results = JSON.parse(resp.body)
     data = results["2015"]
     title = results["meta"]["title"]
     alg = data.slice(*title).to_a
     info = alg.sort_by { |k,v| v["c"] }
```

So I tried to convert the object into an array and from there slice all the content that matches the other array name title and finally sort the information based on their "c" value.

none of this seems to work for me so I have tried to get the data from the object using [] and the name of the key inside, but since each name under the array "title" has \n makes me has to add an extra \ to access it. I want this to be dynamic and not have to modify it every time I have different names under "title"

I need something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7chntms2/6/

Thank you for the help

Comment: I want it in JS @NinaScholz

Comment: how do you get from `["Classic Games\\n", {"c"=>14}],` the 14?

Comment: Thats just a random number but i changed it to make it easier to understand

Comment: ok, please decode `alg = data.slice(*title).to_a` and `info = alg.sort_by { |k,v| v["c"] }` it is hard to understand, what you like to get. please add the important parts to your question and add some example how the result should look like. please do not use data which are not in the example or could not be calculated from the given data.

Comment: Thank you, @Rajesh solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
var obj = {
  "2015": {
    "11": {
      "10": {
        "Family & Friends\nGames": {
          "c": 2
        },
        "Collectible\nGames": {
          "c": 1
        },
        "Logic Games\n": {
          "c": 1
        },
        "Kids Games\n": {
          "c": 1
        }
      },
    },
    "Family & Friends\nGames": {
      "c": 9
    },
    "Collectible\nGames": {
      "c": 2
    },
    "Logic Games\n": {
      "c": 4
    },
    "Kids Games\n": {
      "c": 6
    },
    "Classic Games\n": {
      "c": 3
    },
    "Preschool\nGames": {
      "c": 5
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "id": [
      "[CLY]2",
      "[CLY]7",
      "[CLY]6",
      "[CLY]1",
      "[CLY]4",
      "[CLY]3"
    ],
    "segments": [
      "id",
      "title"
    ],
    "title": [
      "Family & Friends\nGames",
      "Collectible\nGames",
      "Logic Games\n",
      "Kids Games\n",
      "Classic Games\n",
      "Preschool\nGames"
    ]
  }
}

var keys = obj["meta"]["title"];
var newObj = [];

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  newObj.push({
    name: keys[i],
    content: obj["2015"][keys[i]]
  });
}

newObj.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.content.c < b.content.c) return -1;
  if (a.content.c > b.content.c) return 1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: the problem is that the "c " value is no longer there, maybe thats why when i try to run the code gives me this error  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined` @Rajesh

Comment: Can you create a fiddle where we can simulate? Also post the error that you are getting and also explain *the problem is that the "c " value is no longer there*?

Comment: This error means something before c is not defined. Like if you are doing `obj.key.c` check if `obj` and `obj.key` exists. Still a fiddle would be lot better and you would get better answers.

Comment: @Andy when you create a fiddle, its good to have comments but code is necessary. When you say *This is where I get error*, write the code that throws error, as in how are you trying to access value.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help !!!  your answer was correct, there was a typo when i copied and pasted  +1

Answer (score 0):

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wv2kbcyn/

Basically, if the name of that JSON object is data:

```
var meta = data["meta"];
var titles = meta["title"];
var logicgames = titles[2];
```

You can also loop the titles:

```
for(var key in titles)
{
    var title = titles[key];
    console.log(title); // "Family & Friends\nGames", ...
}
```

So `titles` is an array now.

Comment: not really I want to grab the keys that match the names  in "title"

Comment: @Andy Use `if` inside the `for-loop`?

Comment: can you help to convert the obj into an array?